# Express JS Show all events in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

```
var Jsonresult = {};
app.get('/trips', function(req1, res1) {
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
    console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
    Jsonresult.event = event.summary;
    Jsonresult.datetime = start;
    res1.json([Jsonresult]);
  }
  res1.end();
}
```

I am getting events from google calendar. In console showing all events but In POSTMAN showing one data only.
I want to get all results as json format but i am getting only one result from the forloop. Please help me.

I am expecting Results like:

```
[{
"event": "Daily Meeting",
"datetime": "2017-04-25T10:00:00+05:30"
},
{
"event": "Daily Call",
"datetime": "2017-06-26T10:00:00+05:30"
},
{
"event": "Office Meeting",
"datetime": "2017-05-27T10:00:00+05:30"
}]
```

But its showing only one result in POSTMAN like :

```
[{
"event": "Daily Meeting",
"datetime": "2017-04-25T10:00:00+05:30"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is overriding the json content in each iteration. Only the last processed is returned. You should accumulate in an array in order to return an array of events in the response.

```js
var Jsonresult = [];
app.get('/trips', function(req1, res1) {
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
    console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
    var eventJson = {
        event : event.summary,
        datetime : start};
    Jsonresult.push(eventJson);
  }
  res1.json(Jsonresult);
  res1.end();
}
```

This code would be working for you.

As the API definition http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json json method only convert the parameter as JSON string using JSON.stringify method and set the correct content-type for the response